# My Character Mesh has an Inner mesh i can't get rid of

Tags: mesh, duplicate

I'm fairly new to blender but i have an issue where my mesh has an inner mesh that i can't find in my scene collection.

It kinda clips through my top layer too. I can't find the vertex to delete either.

I've no idea how to fix this. ;(

[image]

Second picture showing the visible torso with no selectable vertices:

[image: second picture]

Comment: 1: Please make proper screenshots instead of taking photos of your monitor (and add them in your question, not via external links!). 2: You're in _Edit Mode_ but only one mesh is showing vertices - so the other mesh is not part of this object, which means it seems to be a different object. So just delete the other one. But to select and delete it you have to switch to _Object Mode_. If this is not the case here, please upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions to edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I took a closer look at those screenshots: why do you have two *Mirror* modifiers on the object? The first is set to not mirror on any axis, so it is completely unnecessary, the second is set to mirror on the Y axis - but your mesh has vertices on both sides in -Y and +Y direction. So the extra mesh you see on the left is the right side being mirrored and the extra mesh on the right is the left side being mirrored. When you are using a *Mirror* modifier it is better to only have a mesh on one side of the mirror.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i noticed that now.  Originally i started the mesh with a mirror modifier on a sphere and it was working fine.  I don't understand why it turned off though or if there's any way to get it back like that.

Comment: I tried removing the modifier which worked but then couldn't find a way to have it mirror onto the other side without duplicating the whole thing

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand what you did. There are (or were) two _Mirror_ modifiers on your mesh. The first one on the top with no mirror axis enabled which is useless, so it can be deleted. The second one at the bottom is set to mirror on Y axis, which is okay and you should keep. But then you have to delete one half of the mesh on either -Y or +Y side. Do you know how the _Mirror_ modifier works? Do you generally have problems using it or is it something special with this mesh?